# Why is a part of the code inside a (False) if statement executed?

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a small script which:

1. prints the content of a file (generated by another application) on paper with a matrix printer
2. prints the same line into a backup file
3. removes the original file.

The script runs every minute by a cronjob and works fine as long as there are files to print. If there are no files to print, it prints an empty line on the matrix printer and in the backup file. I don't understand why this happens as i implemented an if statement which checks if there is a file to print before the print command is executed. This behaviour only happens if the script is executed by the cron and not if i execute it manually with `./script.sh`. What's the reason of this? and how can i solve it?

Something i noticed on the side is that if I place an `echo "hi"` command in the script, its printed to the matrix printer and the backup file. I expected that its printed to the console console when it has no `>> something` behind. How does this work?

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make sure the backup directory exists
if [ ! -d /home/user/backup_logprint ]
then
  mkdir /home/user/backup_logprint
fi

# Print the records if there are any
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
filename='_logprint_backup'
printer_path="/dev/usb/lp0"

if [ `ls /tmp/ | grep logprint | wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then 
  for f in `ls /tmp | grep logprint`
  do
    echo `cat /tmp/$f` >> "/home/user/backup_logprint/$date$filename"
    echo `cat /tmp/$f` >> $printer_path
    rm "/tmp/$f"
  done
fi
```

Comment: what happens when you run it like this : `sh ./script.sh` ?

Comment: are you sure `ls /tmp/ | grep logprint` isn't generating some output even if the target file is not available? I'd probably get rid of the `if` and rewrite the `for` as `for f in /tmp/*logprint*; do ... echo/echo/rm; done`

Comment: If you replace the entire script with just the shebang and `echo "hi"`, does it print that on the printer? If so, it's something about how the script is being run, not the script itself.

Comment: Don't ever test the return value of `grep` by parsing its output with `wc` and doing a count.  Just write `if [ ls /tmp/ | grep -q logprint ]; then ...` (You should not be parsing the output of `ls` like this, since this will probably not give you what you want if there exists a file with embedded newlines named `a\nlogprint\b` (or maybe it is what you want!), but that's a completely different issue.)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `echo $(cat /tmp/$f)` (backticks converted to $() both to avoid comment markup and because it's the right thing to do).  That is effectively the same as `cat /tmp/$f` except that it horribly munges whitespace.  If you want to munge the whitespce, it would be much clearer to the reader to write `tr -s \\n ' ' < /tmp/"$f"`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `ls` or an `if` statement. Just use a proper glob in the for loop, and if no file match, the loop won't be entered.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Don't check first; just let mkdir decide if
# anything actually needs to be created.
d=/home/user/backup_logprint
mkdir -p "$d"

filename=$(date +"$d/%Y-%m-%d_logprint_backup")
printer_path="/dev/usb/lp0"

# Cause non-matching globs to expand to an empty
# sequence instead of being treated literally.
shopt -s nullglob
for f in /tmp/*logprint*; do
    cat "$f" > "$printer_path" && mv "$f" "$d"
done
```